# RSpec view test using RR failing - undefined method stub

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec2, rspec-rails, rr

I am using Rails 3.1, RSpec 2.6, and rr 1.0.4 and I get a NoMethodError:

```rb
undefined method `stub' for #<Activity:0x007faa90996190>
```

I am trying to utilize the RSpec test below to test my "Activities" show.haml view. If I change my spec_helper.rb file to use RSpec for mocks instead of rr then the test passes. I have tried changing the syntax of the code but to no success.

I found several websites stating that RSpec and rr do not "play well together and one person provided this [rpsec-rr](https://github.com/josephwilk/rspec-rr) solution which did not work for me.

This is my show.haml_spec.rb

```rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe "activities/show.haml" do
  before(:each) do
    @activity = assign(:activity, stub_model(Activity))
  end

  it "renders attributes in .haml" do
    render
  end
end
```

This is the output from my Eclipse compiler using Aptana Studio

```rb
Failures:

  1) activities/show.haml renders attributes in .haml
     Failure/Error: @activity = assign(:activity, stub_model(Activity))
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `stub' for #<Activity:0x007faa90996190>
     # ./spec/views/activities/show.haml_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.15479 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:
rspec ./spec/views/activities/show.haml_spec.rb:8 # activities/show.haml renders attributes in .haml
```

Any recommendation to an alternate syntax would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Note that as of RR 1.0.5 (released 3/28/2013) this problem should no longer be present -- RR is fully compatible with RSpec 2.